# Почему введенный в форму текст на кириллице плохо отображается в БД.

Tags: apache, php, mysql

Кодировка БД utf8_general_ci, кодировка сайта UTF-8, а русский текст, введенный через форму выглядит так(см. картинку).
http://content.foto.mail.ru/mail/borisov.94/_answers/i-629.jpg

Comment: Проверьте еще раз кодировку сайта. Можно даже дважды. То, что в META - одно, файл сам должен быть сохранен в utf8.

Answer (score 1):

После подключения к БД:

```
mysql_query('set names "utf8"');
```

Comment: Не работает выдает Incorrect string value: '\x94Ð...' for column 'name' at row 1
P.S. тип поля в таблице VARCHAR(64)

Comment: В этом запросе нет слова "name" o_O

@alex_90, кавычки точно нужны?

Comment: mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");

Вот эта 100% работает. Я прсто поменял на utf8.